# Authentication, authorization and user management services

Tags: authentication, web-applications, authorization

I am looking for user authentication and authorization services like the following:

- Stormpath
- Janrain
- DailyCred

Are there other players around? This is the current opinion I have:

- Stormpath has a good SDK and good pricing models, but does not support adding arbitrary data to user profiles
- Janrain basic product, Engage, allows you to log in with social logins but no registration and workflow automation, and to get those features you need to pay (a lot)
- DailyCred seems "immature" and lacks api for Java

Is there a comprehensive solution with a reasonable pricing model (from 0 or little up with the number of users?) My requirements are:

- User authentication (registration and automated workflows)
- User authorization (different level of privileges)
- Adding user data in the registration workflow
- A support for social registration is a plus

Comment: This question was closed on webapp.stackexchange.com what is the correct forum then?

Comment: [UserApp](https://www.userapp.io) is another one. Supports login/signup/password-reset, permissions and features, custom properties to extend the basic user model, social login/OAuth, and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Co-founder of Stormpath here. Very happy to see you're enjoying working w/ the SDKs--a ton of effort went into making them easy to use.

A few data points to help evaluate:

- Kicking off an account verification and password reset workflow is a simple API call in Stormpath. Here's a link to the docs http://www.stormpath.com/docs/java/product-guide#ManageWorkflowAutomation
- Role Based Access Control is supported through our Groups object. You can assign an unlimited number of Groups to an application either programmatically or through the Admin Console at api.stormpath.com.
- We're actively building out custom attributes, which will allow you to add arbitrary data to accounts and groups. This should be out very soon.
- Social sign-on is something we're currently considering but have not put a firm date on it. Would love use case info if you're happy to share-- you can always catch us on chat on our website. stormpath.com

Hope this helps!